# BMW - Reading fault code without OBD reader

Tags: obd-ii, 328i

OK - this is frustrating.  It was dead simple to read the error code on my old 323i using the button on the stalk.

I recently bought a 2014 328i xDrive and for the life of me cannot find a way to show the error code using the iDrive system or some other means.

My engine light came on yesterday.  Normally I would just plug in my OBD reader, but I seem to have bricked it with the vendors last firmware update.

Surely there's a way through some menu item to get the CC-ID code that is causing the fault.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to view fault codes through the iDrive interface.

Sadly, an OBD-II reader is the way to go here.

Comment: Good thing they're pretty cheap and easily available, still it's annoying they took a useful feature away.